# Trouble with Timer_tick not stopping

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I'm very new to programming and vb.net, trying to self teach more so as a hobby, as I have an idea for a program that I would find useful, but I am having trouble getting past this issue and I believe it is to do with the timer.

I have a form of size.(600,600) with one button of size.(450,150) that is set location(100,50) on the form. When clicked I want to move down it's own height, then add a new button in it's place. The code included below works as desired for the first two clicks, but on the third click the button keeps moving and the autoscroll bar extends. I initially thought it was the autoscroll function or the location property, but realised that as the button keeps moving, the timer hasn't stopped. I am aware that the code is probably very clunky in terms of achieving the outcome, and that there are a few lines/variables that are currently skipped over by the compiler (these are from older attempts to figure this out).

I have looked around and can't find the cause of my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if the code block looks messy - first go.

```
Public Class frmOpenScreen
Dim intWButtons, intCreateButtonY, intCreateButtonX 'intTimerTick As Integer
Dim arrWNames() As String
Dim ctrlWButtons As Control
Dim blnAddingW As Boolean

Private Sub btnCreateW_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateW.Click
    'Creates new Button details including handler
    Dim strWName, strWShort As String
    Dim intCreateButtonY2 As Integer
    Static intNumW As Integer
    Dim B As New Button

    strWName = InputBox("Please enter the name name of the button you are creating. Please ensure the spelling is correct.", "Create W")
    If strWName = "" Then
        MsgBox("Nothing Entered.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strWShort = strWName.Replace(" ", "")
    B.Text = strWName
    B.Width = 400
    B.Height = 150
    B.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 21.75)
    B.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    B.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top
    B.Margin = New Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
    'Updates Crucial Data (w name array, number of w buttons inc Create New)
    If intNumW = 0 Then
        ReDim arrWNames(0)
    Else
        intNumW = UBound(arrWNames) + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrWNames(intNumW)
    End If
    arrWNames(intNumW) = strWShort
    intNumW = intNumW + 1
    intWButtons = WButtonCount(intWButtons) + 1
    'updates form with new button and rearranges existing buttons
    intCreateButtonY = btnCreateW.Location.Y
    intCreateButtonX = btnCreateW.Location.X
    ‘intTimerTick = 0
    tmrButtonMove.Enabled = True
    ‘Do While intTimerTick < 16
    ‘    'blank to do nothing
    ‘Loop
    'btnCreateW.Location = New Point(intCreateButtonX, intCreateButtonY + 150)
    B.Location = New Point(intCreateButtonX, intCreateButtonY)
    Me.Controls.Add(B)
    B.Name = "btn" & strWShort
    intCreateButtonY2 = btnCreateW.Location.Y
    If intCreateButtonY2 > Me.Location.Y Then
        Me.AutoScroll = False
        Me.AutoScroll = True
    Else
        Me.AutoScroll = False
    End If
    'MsgBox(intCreateButtonY)
End Sub

Function WButtonCount(ByRef buttoncount As Integer) As Integer
    buttoncount = intWButtons
    If buttoncount = 0 Then
        Return 1
    End If
    Return buttoncount
End Function

Public Sub tmrButtonMove_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrButtonMove.Tick
Dim intTimerTick As Integer
    If intTimerTick > 14 Then
        intTimerTick = 0
    End If
    If btnCreateW.Location.Y <= intCreateButtonY + 150 Then
        btnCreateW.Top = btnCreateW.Top + 10
    End If
    intTimerTick += 1
If intTimerTick = 15 Then
        tmrButtonMove.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

So my current understanding is that the tick event handler should be increasing the timertick variable every time it fires, and that once it has hits 15 it should diable the timer and stop the button moving, but it is not doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntTimerTick is initialized to 0 at the beginning of every Tick event. This won't happen if you declare it to be static:

```
Static Dim intTimerTick As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. It didn't occur to me that the variable was being reinitialized every tick.